# Taking my car to get inspected today in NY

Tags: inspection

I have an 05 Dodge Durango, I am taking it to get it inspected today, but someone ripped off the rear wiper blade a couple months ago, will they fail me due to a missing rear blade?

Comment: I can't answer the question of what your local requirements are but in the UK, the rear wiper is not part of the annual ministry of transport vehicle safety inspection.  Only the front wipers are subject to test.

Comment: Why on earth didn't you fix the problem already if it occurred a couple months ago? Somebody did the same to me as well about 5-6 years ago, and I immediately ordered replacement parts. But anyway, in many cases (at least in Finland) of parts commonly failing such as burn bulbs, they just instruct you to replace it without leading to an inspection failure. I'm not sure however if broken rear wiper blade would be considered a failure in Finland.

Answer (score 5):

From the NYS Vehicle and Traffic Law pages ([excerpts here](http://www.safeny.ny.gov/equi-vt.htm)) I can't see anything that explicitly requires a wiper, however if you do have a wiper with a missing blade, I'd suggest fitting a new blade will be a cheap solution that will stop you worrying.